# Check Owin based claim on MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

My `User.IsInRole("CanChangeData")` is not working, but I can see in the debug menu that the Value `CanChangeData` is in the claims list of the user.

[image]

I want to remove a menu if the user cannot change data in a layout, the `if` return false. `Request.IsAuthenticated` return true.

This is how I add the claims to the user on the `AuthenticationController`

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, input.Username),
                    },
                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role); 

var employe = db.Employes.Single(k => k.User == input.Username);

foreach (var permission in employe.Role.Permissions)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, permission.Nom));
}
```

Why  `User.IsInRole("CanChangeData")` is not catching the claim ?

Comment: A role is not a claim. Roles are defined in AspNetRoles and user bindings in AspNetUserRoles. Claims are different. Try `User.HasClaim()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use claims, using this as an example, you add to the claims as such:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ThisIsTheClaimID", "This is the value"));
```

Then you can use the following code to retrieve it:

```
var myClaimValue = User.FindFirst("ThisIsTheClaimID").Value
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: `User.FindFirst("ThisIsTheClaimID").Value` could throw NullRefference exception

Comment: so could anything without the proper structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the associated claim values like following code,

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity;
var claims = identity.Claims.ToList();

if (claims.Any(x = > x.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.Role && x.ClaimValue == "CanChangeData")) 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to get the claims by their type:

```
public string GetClaimByClaimType(string claimType)
{
    return ((ClaimsPrincipal) Thread.CurrentPrincipal)
        .Claims
        .Where(c => claimType == c.Type)
        .Select(c => c.Value)
        .SingleOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

In your particular case, since you'd call it with:

```
// I would recommend using a custom claim type instead of the MS schema name
var hasCanChangeDataRole =
    GetClaimByClaimType("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role");

var canChangeData = 
    "canChangeData".Equals(hasRole, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Depending on your situation, you could abstract these into more concise methods. Typically I store more complex data types in the claims so my supporting methods for doing these checks is more customized.